# Is there a way to force the order of filters in RestAssured?

Tags: rest-assured

I have a filter that modifies the request headers, and a filter that logs the request. Because the logging filter is applied liberally, I have a testNG listener which appends this implicitly (overriding onStart). The header filter needs to be explicitly called, so that any unattended side effects of this can be carefully handled.

I want the logging filter to log the real request - but after the request is logged, it gets modified (because onStart adds the logging filter, followed by the test which adds the header modifier filter).

Is there a way to force the logging filter to be the last filter run, without having to have each test that uses it to retrieve the filter list and append this at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no such option in REST Assured.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 'ordered' filters have been added as of version 3.0.2

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#ordered-filters

Comment: Actually that was my team's pull request - I probably should have added this to the question myself.